# AngularJS dynamically change template for ng-repeat directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to change the template `ng-repeat` uses to render each element dynamically, as in say on selection of an element switch from a table/list view to an alternate view displaying only that element?

What I want is, upon selection of an element in a `ng-repeat` table/list switch to a display only of the selected element. But I want to keep the `ng-repeat` structure (filters, pagination) in place as I would like to be able to navigate through each element one at a time (left and right say) and at any point return to the table/list with its structure in place.

Maybe it is easier to switch to a new route with the new template once an element is selected but then how could I maintain navigation through only the filtered items and revert back to the saved state of the `ng-repeat` on return to that route?

I hope I explained that well enough, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `ng-switch` directive within the `ng-repeat` directive. Here's a basic example:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-switch on="color.value" >
    <span ng-switch-when="orange" style="background-color:{{color.value}};">{{color.name}}</span>
    <span ng-switch-default>{{color.name}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Full [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/FCHrU/).

**UPDATE**

In the comments Ninja Pants clarified the ultimate goal was to use `ng-include` to include the templates. Here's the updated snippet showing how to do that:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-switch on="color.value" >
    <span ng-switch-when="orange" ng-include src="'template.html'"></span>
    <span ng-switch-when="indigo" ng-include src="'template2.html'"></span>
    <span ng-switch-default>{{color.name}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And a [full Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WZBJJNCkwAJhPwAJrOZS?p=preview).

Comment: Didn't even think of tusing ng-switch, thanks! So I could use ng-switch in combination with ng-include to swap in/out the templates without any issues?

Comment: Seems like it would be possible. Since I don't have any template.urls to work with on jsFiddle it's hard to demo. I tried it using the jsFiddle logo URL as my template URL and it kinda works, so I'm guessing it's ok to use ng-includes - http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/X3aAU/

Comment: This does work, I created a Plunker to try the full implementation - http://plnkr.co/edit/WZBJJNCkwAJhPwAJrOZS?p=preview

Comment: Added another template to the above and works great. Thanks allot!

Comment: Glad you asked this, fun little experiment.